# How to join tables by list of ids in Django ORM

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have two tables - Players and Buildings. For example:

```
class Players(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    buildings = models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], default=list, max_length=100)

class Buildings(models.Model):
    building_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Player can have a lot of buildings, there are in the `Player.buildings` field as list of ids.
I need to write a query to get building information for the player. In Postgres SQL, I got that query:

```
SELECT *
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN buildings b on b.id=ANY(buildings) where p.id = %s;
```

But how I can write that SQL query, using Python and Django ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use singular names for your models.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    buildings = models.ManyToManyField(Building)

class Building(models.Model):
    building_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Now when you want to access the set of buildings for your player you can do the following:

> Player.objects.get("pk of player").buildings.all()